# Gatling pass Map element from session in each request

Tags: java, gatling

I thought this would be a simple ask, but I cannot quite figure out how to implement it in Gatling.
I am running an exec() to get a JSON array from my read endpoint, then extract data from that response to add into my update scenario.
I have

```
      .exec(http("Search for row")
                .post("/app_category/search")
                .body(RawFileBody("search.json"))
                .check(status().is(200))
                  .check( jsonPath("$..uniqueId").findAll().saveAs("uniqueIdList"))
                    .check(jsonPath("$..deptId").findAll().saveAs("deptIdList"))
            )
```

Then I merge the uniqueIdList and deptIdList into a List that kind of looks like this, and save it back into session:

```
[{uniqueId=1, deptId=123}, {uniqueId=2, deptId = 234}]
```

When it's time to execute the update scenario, I am not quite sure how to proceed.

```
   .exec(http("Update")
       .post("/update_data")
       .body(ElFileBody("assign-data.json"))); //
```

I need to replace the values for the corresponding fields in assign-data JSON with the ones extracted from the session List. Am I just going about this the wrong way?
I have seen the exec() nested within a forEach but I m not sure if that entire loop will be executed for each user?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use Gatling's Pebble templating engine support:

- https://pebbletemplates.io/
- https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/request/#pebblestringbody
- https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/request/#pebblefilebody

You don't even need to merge the 2 lists.